# jQuery - How do enable color for WYSIWYG X-Editable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been looking around to find out how to enable color selection with WYSIWYG in X-Editable. Can anyone please help me out thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "color selection" ? You want to color the text ?

Comment: Yes, to be able changes the color directly in the editor.

Comment: If you want a wysiwyg editor look at http://ckeditor.com/demo#inline or http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/inline.php